# class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher does not implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, jboss, okhttp, resteasy, undertow

I'm updating dependencies in my project. Below are the corresponding undertow & resteasy dependecies I'm using.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
   <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
   <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
   <artifactId>undertow-websockets-jsr</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.12.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-undertow</artifactId>
   <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
   <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
   <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
   <version>3.15.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Getting below exception when running the application

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT010009: Servlet ResteasyServlet_<class_name> of type class org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher does not implement jakarta.servlet.Servlet
at io.undertow.servlet.api.ServletInfo.(ServletInfo.java:76)
at io.undertow.servlet.Servlets.servlet(Servlets.java:102)
at com.alacriti.serverless.undertow.server.ServicesServer.doUndertowRespAppDeployment(ServicesServer.java:600)
at com.alacriti.serverless.undertow.server.ServicesServer.createDeploymentInfoAndAddRestApps(ServicesServer.java:574)
at com.alacriti.serverless.undertow.server.ServicesServer.start(ServicesServer.java:365)
at com.alacriti.serverless.undertow.server.ServicesServer.main(ServicesServer.java:1044)

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the version of RESTEasy you're using. The latest version is [6.2.8.Final](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/releases/tag/6.2.8.Final). The 3.15.x version implements the Jakarta REST 2.1 specification which is part of Jakarta EE 8.